Accessing Wifi SSID name - Xcode 15.1
I am creating an app which grabs the current SSID name of the network that the device is connected to and performs some actions on it. I have written the code, but whenever I run this I get the error
nehelper sent invalid result code [1] for Wi-Fi information request

I have added the correct permissions for usage description within the Info section of the main project, and I have handled requesting location permissions from the user.
NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription
NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription

I have seen that as of iOS 12, I need to add com.apple.developer.networking.wifi-info into the entitlement capabilities, on the Signing & Capabilities section, but when pressing the +Capability button, this string is not found, only Wireless Accessory Configuration for MFi devices.
I did find another page that said I need to enable Wifi access info within my developer account, however I can't seem to find where to do this.
Running Xcode 15.1. Device installing the test app is iPhoneX 15.6
What do I need to do to access the SSID name please?

Select your Target in Xcode, go to the "Signing and capabilties" tab.  Click the + sign. Select "Access Wi-Fi information"

I don't have that option to select unfortunately. Xcode 15.1

You should update to Xcode 15.4, but I would be very surprised if it wasn't in 15.1.   Are you selecting your target under "targets" in the middle pane, not  your project.

yup, target app is selected in the middle panel, and on the left, not the tests. with the +Capability pop up displayed, showing it is blank for 'access wi-fi...'
https://ibb.co/64vDLWs

Strange.  Try creating a new project and see if it is available in that project?  As I said you should definitely upgrade to Xcode 15.4.  Also make sure your selected Team doesn't say (Personal Team) - You need to select your paid team.

this is my 3rd project, also created a SwiftUI one which works up to the same point. every time it has the NEHotspotNetwork nehelper sent invalid result code [1] for Wi-Fi information request error.
unfortunately I can't upgrade yet as that involves upgrading to Sonoma, which breaks some of my other toolsets that are used on a daily basis.
thanks for you help troubleshooting.

Also make sure your selected Team doesn't say (Personal Team) - You need to select your paid team
could this be the issue? I only have a personal dev account, not a paid one.

Ok, Without a paid dev account you will not be able to add the entitlement.

You need to have a paid developer membership to add the "Access Wifi information" capability.
Without this capability you will not be able to obtain the current SSID.
For reference, the capabilities available under the various membership types are listed on this page.  The third column, "Apple Developer" is the free level.  The first column, ADP (Apple Developer Program) is the paid level.

